# Use git rebase because is easier to revert changes?

Tags: git, merge, rebase, git-revert

I wonder how git rebase helps reverting changes. I cannot understand why rebase is easier than merging for reverting changes.

## Update 1:

Reverting a change I mean, reverting a previous version of master.

- Master v1
- Master v2
- Master v3
- Master v4
- Master v5

At this point I want to revert to `Master v4` for example.

## Update 2:

When I mean helps I don't mean that you revert using rebase or merge.

I will explain better what my colleague said:

For example you have this log:

- Commit time 1: master initially [tag-x]
- Commit time 2: branch `a` from master
- Commit time 3: branch `b` from master
- Commit time 4: random commit on branch `a`
- Commit time 5: random commit on branch `b`
- Commit time 6: put branch `a` into master with merge [tag-a]
- Commit time 7: put branch `b` into master with merge [tag-b]

He says that is more difficult to revert because the commits are not all grouped together. But to me makes no sense, if you revert one tag, let's say [tag-a], master doesn't have the changes from branch `b`. I also don't care about when the commits on branch `b` has been made, even if they are interlaced (in time) with the commits in branch `a`. Or I'm missing a really big point in how git works...

When I revert to [tag-a] I don't really care how many commits have been done in master, I just get what master was at the [tag-a], simple, independently by how many commits and when they have been made.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "reverting changes", particularly how does it relate to merge vs rebase?  Care to explain your question a little bit more?

Comment: Hi! I've updated  my question, thanks

Comment: In git context, you don't "revert to" anything, you "reset to" something. Reverting is undoing changes of one commit by creating a new commit, see: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert

Answer (score 3):

When rebasing - the tree is more straight without unnecessary "branches" (by branches I mean literaly branches on the structure of the commits tree, not "git branch") and it makes it easier to find a certain stage to revert to.
When lots of people work with one repo merging it every time creates a veeeery complicated tree structure.

Comment: But if you know the `Master v4` commit, then you could just checkout that commit and commit the diff between `Master v5` and `Master v4`, right?

Comment: Well, yes, but if you're reverting the change, why do that?  Besides, doing that throws away `Master v5`'s history, since you're just creating one commit on top of `Master v4` with all the changes between those two branches.

Comment: No, sorry, by doing that you will have Master  v4, Master v5 and Master v4 again.

Comment: Oh you mean creating a commit like `git revert` would?  Yeah, I guess you could do that.  But that's what `git revert` is there for.  `git revert master-v5` does what you're describing, basically.

Comment: i was thinking your question is based on some sort of "conventional" wisdom about rebase vs. merge and you wanted to dispute it ) my idea was that it's less complicated to manipulate rebased repo than a merged one from the point of view of a not very experienced user - thats all. In other cases (esp. from technical point of view) I think there's hardly any difference

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in that case, you probably want neither rebase nor merge.  Depending on the use case, you want either `git revert`, or `git reset`.

`Revert` will allow you to create one or more commits that revert the changes introduced in one or more commits.  `Reset` will essentially remove the commits from history.

In the case you described, you can either `git revert` the change introduced in `v5`, creating a new commit that reverses those changes, or you can `git reset --hard` to `v4`, which will remove the commit `v5` from the history.

Both have advantages and disadvantages, and should be used in different cases for different reasons.  For example, if the branch is public, and being worked on by multiple developers, you want to avoid `git reset --hard`, since that will mess up any commits other developers may have made based off `v5`.  On the other hand, if you're working locally, and simply decided to abandon any work you had started on `v5`, then introducing a commit to reverse that change (with `git revert`) will only introduce noise into the branch's history.

You can read up more on [`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert), and on [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) on git's web site.

Edit:

Hm, it seems I misunderstood your question... you're asking why it's easier to revert to an old state when you've been using `rebase` rather than `merge` to bring in feature branches.

If that's the case, then Dmitriy M's answer explains why: a branch which is rebased onto is linear, while one that is merged onto is more complex, so finding out which commit(s) to revert, or reset to, is simpler.

On the other hand, if what you're really trying to do is undo bringing in a branch into `master`, it's easier to figure out which commit to `reset` to if you've been merging rather than rebasing, especially if you use `merge --no-ff`, since you can simply look for the merge commit that brings in the branch (which should read something like "Merge branch XXX onto master"), and `reset` to its parent on the `master` side.  For example, if you want to undo bring in the branch `feature-a` into `master`, and the merge commit, which reads "Merge feature-a into master" has a hash starting with `87db280`, then you can just `git reset 87db280^`, or `git reset 87db280~1`.

Comment: Hi! I've updated my question, I think you misunderstood my question.

Comment: Yup, I noticed, after Dmitriy M answered.  Basically, if you've tagged your "version" commits, then reverting to a past state is just as simple in either case (just `git reset --hard <commit-tag>` or something similar).  You're right in saying that the time those commits happened is irrelevant to the operation.  In fact, if what you're trying to do is "undo" bringing in a branch into `master`, it's easier if you've merged, since you can revert to the merge commit's parent on the `master` side and be done with it.  Doing something similar if you've rebased is not trivial.

Answer (score -3):

Rebase will keep history of commits from both paths (shown as one set on top of the other set). Merge will lose the history of one of the two paths.

Comment: Merge will not lose any history.  A non-fast-forward merge has two or more parents, one for the base branch, and one for each branch that was merged onto it.  The history of all these branches can be accessed through each of those parents.  Rebase, on the other hand, "changes" history (that is, the new, rebased commits, have their hashes, times, and parents changed), so some history is lost.